# Vertically center text inside grid element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to vertically center text inside grid item, which has minHeigh attribute set, [here's short codesandbox example of the problem i'm facing](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3q58jy8y7), justify, alignItems, does not seem to be working.

```
  <Grid container className={classes.root}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={16}
        className={classes.demo}
        alignItems={alignItems}
        direction={direction}
        justify={justify}
      >
        {[0, 1, 2].map(value => (
          <Grid
            key={value}
            item
            style={{
              padding: "0 12px",
              minHeight: 48,
              borderStyle: "solid"
            }}
          >
            {`Cell ${value + 2}`}
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

When `style={{ minHeight: 48 }}` is applied to `<Grid item />` children of grid item is not being aligned, justify, alignItems, does not have any effect on it.

Comment: Please provide more detail about your issue and add your relevant code directly to your question. That makes it way easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: Could you please give us some of your code? This would definetly help to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two other properties to the element as well.

```
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
```

If this is the result that you are expecting

[image]

```
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={16}
        className={classes.demo}
        alignItems={alignItems}
        direction={direction}
        justify={justify}
      >
        {[0, 1, 2].map(value => (
          <Grid
            key={value}
            item
            style={{
              display: "inline-flex", // <--
              alignItems: "center",   // <--
              padding: "0 12px",
              minHeight: 48,
              borderStyle: "solid"
            }}
          >
            <p>{`Cell ${value + 2}`}</p>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertical-align: middle`, and see if that works? Or if the box is a fixed height you could always add margin to the top of it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it. Wrap your text inside div and use alignItems:
   https://codesandbox.io/s/8nw8v9yv02